# Graph Theory - Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) Question

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization

Let $ = (,)$ be an undirected connected weighted graph.

For a spanning tree $$ of $$, let ($$) be the maximum weight of an edge in $$.

An economic tree of a graph $$ is a spanning tree of $$ with a minimal possible .

True/False: If $$ is a MST of $$, then $$ is an economic tree of $$.

---

I assume that this one is true.

I want to assume towards a contradiction that $T$ is a MST that is not an economic tree, and try to get a contradiction that T can't be a MST anymore.

I struggle to prove it, I will appreciate some hints!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given $G$ and a weight $w$ you can define $G_{w}$ as the graph with the same nodes and only the edges of length $\leq w.$ Then the minimal $MaxCost$ is the largest $w$ such that $G_w$ is not connected. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, any MST is an economic tree.

You can prove that the maximum cost of an edge in an MST is equal to the minimum cost $c$ such that the graph restricted to edges of weight at most $c$ is connected.

This will imply your proposition.

More details. Let $w : E \to \mathbb{N}$ be the weight function. For $t \in \mathbb{N}$, let $G_t = (V,\{e \in E : w(e) \leq t\}$, and let $t_0$ be minimum such that $G_{t_0}$ is connected. Also let $T \subseteq E$ be a minimum cost spanning tree, and $w_T = \max_{e \in T} w(e)$. We want to prove $w_t = t_0$.

To prove that $w_T \geq t_0$, you just have to prove that $G_{w_T}$ is connected, which should be easy, then it follows by the choice of $t_0$.

To prove that $w_T \leq t_0$, we need this proposition:

**Proposition:** for any minimum spanning tree $T \subseteq E$ and any $e \in T$, there is a cut $\delta(X)$ in $G$ such that $e \in \delta(X)$ and $w(e) = \min_{e' \in \delta(X)} w(e')$.

You can choose for $X$ one of the two connected component of $T \setminus e$.

Comment: My personal attempts to prove this have failed. Can you give some hint of the proof?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain more please?

Comment: I added some hints.

Comment: Thank you for that! I think that assuming towards contradiction should be easier that building another graph, but I miss its main point to prove...

Comment: You can prove it by contradiction, but it will use same argument anyways. If $T$ is not economic, take an edge $e \in T$ with $w(e) > t_0$. Then use the proposition to say that $e$ is an edge of min-cost in some cut. But that is not possible because there must be an edge of cost at most $t_0$ in that cut (because $G_{t_0}$ is connected). So in the end, you will prove the same things as my proposal, but you will prove them under a contradictory assumption, hence you won't be able to re-use the partial results obtained. The proposition is a useful result that you will find in many textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong Answer left for the record.**

Unless I am interpreting your definitions incorrectly, this is false.

Consider $C_4$, with edge weights $1,1,1,2$. Then any three adjacent edges comprise a minimal spanning tree, but three of the four minimal spanning trees are not economic.

Comment: I assumed the MST was minimal total weight. But unsure.

Comment: What is your definition of $MST$? If you additionally require it is minimal in weight among minimal spanning trees, this is worth mentioning. It changes the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

Comment: All spanning trees are minimal if you ignore the weights, @william. No proper subtree of a spanning tree spans all the points of the graph, and all spanning trees have the same number of nodes and edges.

Comment: You're very right. I'll leave this answer up for the record, but it's decidably wrong.

Comment: Then edit your weong answer to make it clear it is wrong. Somebody coming along five years from now shouldn’t have to read the comments to know the answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for trying William